# Put/Get BLOB on Azure using Android

Tags: android, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload files to Azure Server in my Android App. I am using these libraries: https://github.com/microsoft-dpe/wa-toolkit-android

In these libraries I know what methods to call for putting BLOB on server (putBlockBlob()). But I need help on how to create Blob or BlobData from Files in Android. Could not find any link to this. If any one has worked on Azure in Android before, please guide me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The default api functions for Blob Storage are looking for Byte arrays.

So if your content in Android can be stored as a binary byte array, you should be able to pass it to the PutBlob function. Get Blob will also return a byte array that you would then have to cast back to your internal content.